# How many lines are determined by $n$ coplanar points (no three of which are collinear)?

Tags: geometry

I have a problem in which I need to find how many lines there would be if there are n points. No 3 points are collinear. All points are coplanar. I have figured out this much:

| Lines | Points |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 15 | 6 |
| So on... |  |

I have noticed that the increment between the number of lines is one. 
So:
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
6 + 4 = 10
10 + 5 = 15
Thank you!

Comment: In the event you downvote this, could you please give a reason why? Duplicate? Poor quality? I would love to improve the quality of the question.

Comment: The answer is the $n$th triangular number, given by the formulae $$T(n)={n+1\choose2}=\frac{n(n+1)}2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k$$

Comment: @SammyBlack Are you sure? How about vertices of a square?

Comment: What space are you referencing? Is this $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, or some other space? Also, this question is asked here: https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Permutations.faq.question.476358.html I have not fully read the site, only found it.

Comment: @JonathanMiller does it matter whether it is $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @JackyChong No, I suppose it does not matter. Two points needed for a line does not matter what $\mathbb{R}^n$ the points are in. I suppose $\mathbb{R}^2$ might be a good toy problem before generalising to $n > 2$.

Comment: @SammyBlack I believe you are overcomplicating the problem. It is just $n$ choose two points.

Comment: @JonathanMiller I don't even think there's any generalization.

Comment: Further to the conversation, A paper by the late mathematician 
Aiden Bruen published: The Number of Lines Determined by $n^2$ Points (1971), https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82538573.pdf It is full of proofs.

Comment: @JackyChong, you're correct. I deleted my unhelpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonathanMiller has a website that has the answer. The formula is: $$ \frac{x(x-1)}{2} $$